# How do I display list items in a line in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, title

I want to make a ggplot title (Text) out of two elements generating in a loop:

```
Text = c(unique(ID_Role_table$ID), unique(ID_Role_table$Role))
```

Obviously, I get a list here (so they display vertically). I was wondering whether I could display them horizontally, or if there´s another way of writing the title.

Thank you!

Comment: Try with `paste(unique(ID_Role_table$ID), unique(ID_Role_table$Role))`.

Comment: or `unlist(Text)`